# navigator.credentials is null on local server

Tags: javascript, browser, server, credentials, webauthn

here is my problem : I try to use the Credential Management API to access to authenticators on my webapp : 
`navigator.credentials.create()` and `navigator.credentials.get()`.

I have no problem when I execute my code on localhost, and the webapp is asking for my security key. But when I am on my local server, with the exact same code, `navigator.credentials` is undefined although I am using the same browser.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

`(window.PasswordCredential || window.FederatedCredential)` returns `false`, only on my server 192.168.x.x but I don't know why. I am on Chrome 74.

How could I resolve this problem ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

WebAuthn javascript will work only when used with HTTPS or on the `localhost` hostname (in this case HTTPS is not required).

It seems that you are using an IP address.

Comment: Thank you. This works. The issue with my code was that I was using "localhost.com" instead of "localhost" and it was throwing "navigator.credentials is undefined" error.